# Check if any value in list satisfies a condition

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate, jdbc

Suppose I have the following table called `Seasons`:

| ... | start_month | end_month |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ... | 2 | 6 |
| ... | 3 | 4 |
| ... | ... | ... |

I need to write a query which, for a given list of months, returns all the `Seasons` that satisfy the condition where at least 1 month in the list is: `start_month <= month <= end_month`.

I've written this query as a native query with JDBC, except the where clause.

```
@Repository
public class SeasonsRepositoryImpl implements SeasonsRepositoryCustom {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    public List<SeasonsProjection> findByMonths(List<Integer> months) {
        String query = "select * " +
                       "from seasons as s" +
                       "where ...."

        try {
            return  em.createNativeQuery(query)
                    .setParameter("months", months)
                    .unwrap(org.hibernate.query.NativeQuery.class)
                    .setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(SeasonsProjection.class))
                    .getResultList();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Exception with an exception message: {}", e.getMessage());
            throw e;
        }
    }

}
```

I have no idea how to write this, I thought of using the ANY operator until I found out that ANY only works with tables and not lists, I thought of writing this as a subquery with converting the list to a table, but I don't know if that's possible, I couldn't find anything in the MySQL documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to accomplish this is:

```
select s.* 
from (select 1 as mn union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8
   union select 9 union select 10 union select 11 union select 12) as a
inner join season s on a.mn between s.start_month and s.end_month
where a.mn in (:flexibleTypeMonths);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your where clause, you will want to have an OR conditions for each month.
You can generate it in a loop and then concat or something similar.

Your final query for input of 1,3,4,7 for example will look as follows:

```
SELECT *
FROM seasons as s
WHERE (1 between start_month and end_month
OR 3 between start_month and end_month
OR 4 between start_month and end_month
OR 7 between start_month and end_month)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, although this will definitely solve the problem, I was thinking more of a non programmatic, SQL only solution that I would be able to execute as a standalone query.

Comment: `SQL only solution that I would be able to execute as a standalone query` -   

How will you deal with the input (list of months)? Will you be storing it as a table with a single column?

Comment: Yeah you're right, scratch that part then, I want to know how to solve this with SQL. The thing is this is a really big and some what complex query, I obviously omitted all the non important stuff because this is the part where I'm stuck at. Adding a for loop when this is already complex enough doesn't cut it for me.

Comment: First, the query above is far from complex I would say, but if you want `sql only` solution, I can suggest storing the list of months in a table and then join the two together like so `select distinct seasons.* from seasons s, month_list ml where ml.month 
between s.start_month and s.end_month`  
However, this solution will also require "some sort" of a loop, in order to insert the list into the db